# Grab Metadata for All objects in S3 bucket

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am currently tagging objects in s3 by attaching a metadata tag containing a md5 hash. When I am uploading the objects I check that the md5 hash is different before I push the object into s3.

I was wondering if there is a way to grab the metadata for all the objects in an s3 bucket, as it seems to take sometime to grab them individually for each item.

I am using the following to grab the hash from s3

```
$hash = Get-S3ObjectMetadata -Credential $AwsCredentials -BucketName $Bucketname -Key $key
```

When I remove the -Key value I get the following Error

```
Get-S3ObjectMetadata : Key is a required property and must be set before making this call.
```

I also tried get-help -full and got the following information on the -key

```
    -Key <System.String>
    The key of the object.

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    2
    Default value                None
    Accept pipeline input?       True (ByPropertyName)
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

Which seems to contradict the error I get

Comment: Is `$key` set?  It seems not.  And the MD5 of the object is already available as an attribute of the object.

Comment: I want to be able to grab an entire bucket, rather than each of the files individually and that's why I want to remove the Key. I've tried using a part of the Key, like the folder names in s3, but that isn't working and returns a different error. As for the MD5 already available, the closest I found was the E-Tag which is similar, but apparently isn't the actual MD5 hash of the Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetching object metadata has no batch mode.  You have to fetch each object's metadata individually.  The usual approach is to work with multiple processes or threads to send parallel requests.  A bucket should be able to handle such requests at a rate of several hundred reqs/sec with no problems.

Your solution is flawed, since it will not scale.  One solution I have seen is to actually set the object key to the hash of the object payload (sha256 is a better choice, since there are known collisions for both md5 and sha1) which provides essentially automatic deduplication.

Unless you are using `SSE-C` or `SSE-KMS`, the etag is the md5sum of the object body *or* the md5sum of the binary (not hex) md5sums of the individual parts, followed by `-` and the number of parts, when the object is uploaded using the multipart upload API.