# How to get s3 metadata for all keys in a bucket via boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to fetch all metadata for a bucket with a prefix via Boto. There are a few SO questions that imply [this isn't possible via the AWS API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879347/grab-metadata-for-all-objects-in-s3-bucket). So, two questions:

1. Is there a good reason this shouldn't be possible via the AWS API?
2. Although [I can't find one in docs](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/s3_tut.html#setting-getting-metadata-values-on-key-objects), Is there a convenience method for this in Boto?

I'm currently doing this using multithreading, but that seems like overkill, and I'd really rather avoid it if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

While there isn't a way to do this directly through boto, you could add an inventory configuration on the bucket(s) which generates a daily CSV / ORC file with all file metadata.

Once this has been generated you can then process the output rather than multithreading or any other method that requires a huge number of requests.

See: [`put_bucket_inventory_configuration`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_inventory_configuration)

Its worth noting that it can take upto 48 hours for the first one to be generated.